# HttpInvoker get choked when trying to return a list with 1000 elements

Tags: hessian, spring-remoting, httpinvoker

I wrote a small service class which return a list with 1000 strings.
I am using Spring Httpinvoker to get the service and read the list. If the number of the elements in the list is 100 all is going well when
I try 1000 it freeze utill there is a connection reset
The client side is JUnit 4 class with Spring runner on the same machine
by the way the same is happening with Hessian protocol using the Spring Remoting classes. 
They are both HTML based but this is the only connection I can see RMI and JMS RMI (thorugh Spring remoting) is working fine with the same service
The service code

```
public class DateServiceImpl implements DateService {


/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see com.successcharging.rmiexample.DateService#getDate()
 */
@Override
public Date getDate() {
    return new Date();
}

@Override
public List<String> getBigList() {
    List<String> listData = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 100;i++) {
        listData.add(Math.random()+"");
    }
    return listData;
}

}
```

The mapping server side

```
<!-- The service to use this is the server side -->
<bean id="dateServiceServer"     class="com.successcharging.rmiexample.server.DateServiceImpl" />
<!-- the http invoker protocol -->
<bean name="/DateServiceHttpInvoker"
    class="org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerServiceExporter">
    <property name="service" ref="dateServiceServer" />
    <property name="serviceInterface"
        value="com.successcharging.rmiexample.server.DateService" />
</bean>
```

The client mapping

The junit code

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class DateServiceTest extends BaseTest {

@Resource
private DateService dateServiceHttpInvokerClient;


@Test
public void testDateServiceHttpInvoker() {
    List<String> data = dateServiceHttpInvokerClient.getBigList(); //Here it is get stuck
    data.add("My test");
    System.out.println("HttpInvoker:"
            + data.size());
}

public DateService getDateServiceHttpInvokerClient() {
    return dateServiceHttpInvokerClient;
}

public void setDateServiceHttpInvokerClient(
        DateService dateServiceHttpInvoker) {
    this.dateServiceHttpInvokerClient = dateServiceHttpInvoker;
}
}
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Did you ever get traction on this?  I'm running into a similar problem.  If I make a request, it always completes fine.  If I make many repeated-requests in quick-succession everything suddenly freezes up for several seconds until finally getting a "SocketException: Connection reset"-error.

???

Comment: To tell you the truth this happened to me only in my test porject In my real project I did not meet the same problem. I can not tell you what I did diffrently sorry